# Unrelated Values of DropDownList in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.
I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.
I have a model 'Poste' which contains some attributs.
The Views of Poste (create,edit,delete...) are created automaticaly when i creat the controller.
I have a Foreign Key in this model.
The values of this foreign key are showen in a 'DropDownList'.
The problem is that those value aren't related to the right table of my foreign Key.
TO EXPLAIN MORE :
I have 3 tables which are :

- Poste (**ID_Poste**, Nom_Poste,...,#ID_Ligne)
- Ligne (**ID_Ligne**, #ID_UF)
- UF (**ID_UF**)

In my form, the DropDownList is used normaly to show the **ID_Ligne** (which the foreign key in the table Poste) but infact , the values shown are of the table **UF** (ID_UF precisely).
So, it is a projection of the table UF. 
I don't know the reason.
I am sorry for the english ,,,and it is not clear enough, i will try to explain more.
Here is the model of Poste :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Poste
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "ID Poste :")]
        public string ID_Poste { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nom Poste:")]
        public string nom_Poste { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Application :")]
        public string Application { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "In Poste :")]
        public string In_Po { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Out Poste :")]
        public string Out_Po { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Etat :")]
        public string Etat { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Ligne")]
        [Display(Name = "ID Ligne :")]
        public string ID_Ligne { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Mouvement :")]
        public string Mouvement { get; set; }

        public virtual Ligne Ligne { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Ligne> Lignes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Poste> Postes { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

And this the Controller :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{ 
    public class PosteController : Controller
    {
        private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();

        //
        // GET: /Poste/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var postes = db.Postes.Include(p => p.Ligne);
            return View(postes.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Poste/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(string id)
        {
            Poste poste = db.Postes.Find(id);
            return View(poste);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Poste/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ID_Ligne = new SelectList(db.Lignes, "ID_Ligne", "ID_UF");
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Poste/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Poste poste)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Postes.Add(poste);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            ViewBag.ID_Ligne = new SelectList(db.Lignes, "ID_Ligne", "ID_UF", poste.ID_Ligne);
            return View(poste);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Poste/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            Poste poste = db.Postes.Find(id);
            ViewBag.ID_Ligne = new SelectList(db.Lignes, "ID_Ligne", "ID_UF", poste.ID_Ligne);
            return View(poste);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Poste/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Poste poste)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(poste).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.ID_Ligne = new SelectList(db.Lignes, "ID_Ligne", "ID_UF", poste.ID_Ligne);
            return View(poste);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Poste/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            Poste poste = db.Postes.Find(id);
            return View(poste);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Poste/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {            
            Poste poste = db.Postes.Find(id);
            db.Postes.Remove(poste);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

And finaly the View of Create :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.Poste>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Create
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Ajouter</h2>

<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Poste</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_Poste) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID_Poste) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Poste) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.nom_Poste) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.nom_Poste) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nom_Poste) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Application) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Application) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Application) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.In_Po) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.In_Po) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.In_Po) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Out_Po) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Out_Po) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Out_Po) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Etat) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Etat) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Etat) %>
        </div>



        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_Ligne, "Ligne") %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.DropDownList("ID_Ligne", String.Empty) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Ligne) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mouvement) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mouvement) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mouvement) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" />
            <input type="reset" value="Vider" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Retour à la liste", "Index") %>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

> Ps : After the execution, a new column **(Poste_ID_Poste)** is created
>   automaticaly in my base in 2 tables : Poste and Ligne.

Answer (score 0):

You have an ICollection of Poste's on your Poste class.  I am not 100% sure but that sounds like a cyclical reference to me (you have a class that is a collection of itself)

You also have a virtual of Lignes and an IEnumerable of Lignes.  I don't think you are properly using either of the previously two mentioned items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used the same methode with a Table USER and and Table Account. And it works perfectly, the problem here I think that the Table Ligne has also a Foreign Key in another table (UF) which isn't the case for the example of USER and Account